# Save drag and drop location to local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, save

I have some links that will be sortable depending on most frequently used. I have the drag and drop down, but can't figure out how to save it so when page reloads the positions don't change. **Preferably** locally saved so each person has their own results. I've looked at several examples but couldn't find one that would work with mine. Anyone have any idea on how I can do this? Here's what I have so far:

Still new to stack overflow. For some reason when I post the code it doesn't show the result as it should be.

Thanks.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.event').on("dragstart", function(event) {
      var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
      dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (event.type === 'drop') {
        var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
        if ($(this).find('span').length === 0) {
          de = $('#' + data).detach();
          de.appendTo($(this));
        }

      };
    });
  })

});

// tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
if (window.parent && window.parent.parent) {
  window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
    height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    slug: "None"
  }], "*")
}
```

```css
table th,
table td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
}

table span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="#table1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<table id="#table2" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>List</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="event" id="a" draggable="true"><a href="http://placeholder.net">Content A</a></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="event" id="b" draggable="true"><a href="http://placeholder.net">Content B</a></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="event" id="c" draggable="true"><a href="http://placeholder.net">Content C</a></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="event" id="d" draggable="true"><a href="http://placeholder.net">Content D</a></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I fixed your snippet, FYI (no HTML `style` tags in the CSS part). You'll have to implement your own system to save the state whenever it changes, and to load it from storage when the page is reloaded. You'll probably want to use the [Web Storage APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. It's the localstorage side of this that I am having the most trouble with. I've been looking for some demo's that are similar to this particular drag and drop method, but haven't found any I can learn off of.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle in case someone has any ideas they want to test.
The thing I am trying to do is save the positions of the content into the box they are dragged to. But have them saved to localstorage, so when I close the window and come back, they are saved to that customized position for each person.
https://jsfiddle.net/Foregotten/1orub1p2/